# How to mock a nested method?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I'm learning more about Jasmine Unit Testing and I've ran into something that I can't figure out. I'm new to both JavaScript and Unit Testing. I've tried to look for examples about nested methods and mocking them, but I'm still unable to have a successful test. I'm making a game with PhaserJS (HTML5 Game Library) and I've written successful tests so far. This is an example of my successful test.

```
 function createGameScreenBorder(gameState) {
      var border = gameState.game.add.graphics();
    }
```

This is my test block.

```
it("create gamescreen background border", function() {
    gameState.game = {
    add: jasmine.createSpyObj('add', ['graphics'])
    };
      createGameScreenBorder(gameState);
      expect(gameState.game.add.graphics).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Now the above code works, it doesn't do much. What I want is to draw a rectangle which is a method part of the graphics method.

```
function createGameScreenBorder(gameState) {
      var border = gameState.game.add.graphics();
          // drawRect: x, y width, length
          border.drawRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
      }
```

This is my test block.

```
    it("create gamescreen background border", function() {
          gameState.game = {
            add: {
              graphics: jasmine.createSpyObj('graphics', ['drawRect'])
            }
          }
          createGameScreenBorder(gameState);
          expect(gameState.game.add.graphics).toHaveBeenCalled();
          expect(gameState.game.add.graphics().lineStyle).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0,0,0,0);
        });
```

I want to be able to make sure that drawRect() is called with my parameters, but I am confused as to how to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gameState.game.add.graphics()` returns an object that has a `drawRect()` method on it.

First you want to check if the `gameState.game.add.graphics()` was called - this is already done. Then check if the `drawRect()` was called on the object returned from this method. To do that, set up your spy to return an object that also has a spy on it.

```
it("create gamescreen background border", function() {
  let resultObject = {
    drawRect: jasmine.createSpy()
  };

  gameState.game.add = {
    graphics: jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(() => {
      return resultObject;
    })
  };

  createGameScreenBorder(gameState);

  expect(gameState.game.add.graphics).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(resultObject.drawRect).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0, 0, 0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped a lot!!